# Infimum simple function and stepfunction

Tags: general-topology

If $A_n$ is a simple function and $B_n$ is a Stepfunction, then the infimum ($A_n\wedge B_n$) is a stepfunction. Why is this true?

Comment: Please look at my edit to this question.  It you enter "latex symbols" into Google, you can find out about things like this.

Comment: What is you definition of a step function and a simple function? Are $A_n$, $B_n$ assumed to be non-negative?